Error copying file to container using Podman on Windows 11
I'm trying to run a SQL script against a SQL Server instance that is running inside a Podman container on a Windows 11 host.
To do this, I'm attempting to copy the script file to the container using the following command:
podman cp .\baseline.sql mssql-server-1:/tmp/baseline.sql

it returns:

error rewriting "c:....\baseline.sql" to be relative to "/": expected root directory to be an absolute path, got "/"

It seams the paths are ok, because if I change either the source or destination Podman reports correctly the error.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or can provide insight into what might be going wrong here? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

This is generally followed by containers/podman issue 14862:

In the meantime as a workaround you can access your windows drive through the mount that is on the wsl linux host, using unix path conventions, like this:
podman cp /mnt/c/users/foo/bar/file.bak mycontainer:/var/opt/backups


And:

I was able to get a file copy into my container working with the following.
I redeployed my podman machine, rebuilt my container...
this does work:
wsl -d podman-machine-default -u user enterns podman cp \
    /mnt/d/2022_Projects/assessments/HK197500195.bin se92:/root/


Or:

wsl -d podman-machine-default -u user enterns podman cp \
    /mnt/c/"your file location" container:/sql/


Meaning:

"Prefixing" docker cp with wsl -d podman-machine-default -u user enterns also worked for me. Concretely, I wrote:
wsl -d podman-machine-default -u user enterns podman cp \
    "myfile.txt" my-container-name:/tmp/


Also:

Simple workaround for me is to use podman machine ssh command like this:
podman machine ssh "podman cp /mnt/c/dev/file.py container:/usr/src/app"



If anyone is interested in performing the contrary (copying from container to actual disk in Windows 11) I found working this command
podman cp <container_id>:<path_to_file_in_container> <windows_path>

Where actual_path is something like "/Users//Downloads/" because the command line tool interpret the first "/" as "C:/". In fact if you write instead "C:\Users<username>\Downloads" you would get the error
Error: "/Users/<username>/Downloads/" could not be found on container C: no such file or directory
